# Using pyinstaller to build exe

Tags: python, twisted, exe, pyside, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller on windows to build exe of application containing pyside & twisted. My problem is that, exe file getting generated but on double click nothing is happening. 
On further analysis, when I run exe from 'dist' folder using command prompt, it shows following error,

```
 File "E:\pyinstaller-2.0\proj\build\pyi.win32\proj\out00-PYZ.
yz\dbhash", line 18, in open
 File "E:\pyinstaller-2.0\proj\build\pyi.win32\proj\out00-PYZ.
yz\bsddb", line 364, in hashopen
sddb.db.DBNoSuchFileError: (2, 'No such file or directory')
```

Does anybody know a solution?

Thnx in advance

I have tried by adding '.' in PYTHONPATH but not getting success.

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed. Error was occurring due to installation of twisted dependencies in wrong order. Using following post I reinstall everything then it is fixed.

http://www.metamul.com/blog/installing-python-twisted-on-windows/

Thank you